# Como funciona o algoritmo DES?

Tags: algoritmo, segurança, criptografia

Estou com dúvida sobre como funciona o Data Encryption Standard, alguém poderia explicar de forma didática?

Comment: Ola Lucas, bem vindo ao StackOverflow, acho que este link pode te ajudar no que está procurando: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard

Answer (score 2):

### O que é o DES?

O **DES (Data Encryptation Standart) (ou em português, padrão de encriptação de informação)** é um método de obter uma chave assimétrica para uma informação virtual, mas hoje já se encontra **obsoleto**, sistemas de criptografia avançados não usam mais este algoritmo.

O algoritmo era controverso e usava uma chave assimétrica de tamanho pequeno, o DES deu inspiração para criação de outros algoritmos mais seguros, como o [TripleDES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES).

*Retirado do Wikipédia:*

> DES é tipo de cifra em bloco, ou seja, um algoritmo que toma uma `String` de **tamanho fixo** de um texto plano e a transforma, através de uma série de complicadas operações, em um texto cifrado de mesmo tamanho. No caso do DES, o tamanho do bloco é 64 bits. DES também usa uma chave para personalizar/cifrar a transformação, de modo que a descriptografia somente seria possível, teoricamente, por aqueles que conhecem a chave particular utilizada para criptografar (*key*). A chave consiste nominalmente de **64 bits**, porém somente 56 deles são realmente utilizados pelo algoritmo. Os oito bits restantes são utilizados para verificar a paridade e depois são descartados, portanto o tamanho efetivo da chave é de 56 bits, e assim é citado o tamanho de sua chave.

### Encriptação limitada

Em resumo, é o algoritmo mais antigo e "seguro" usado para encriptar textos de tamanho fixo usando uma chave de tamanho fixo.

Seu algoritmo é constituído por 16 estágios, os denominados "Rounds", e existem as permutações inicial e final, denominadas *IP* e *FP*, sendo *IP* desfaz o quê *FP* fez, e vice-versa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essas permutações não fazem significância nenhuma para criptografia em si, foi usada apenas para facilitar o processo de decodificar e codificar informações.

### Não vale a pena investir

A explicação do algoritmo é grande e avançada, e requer um pouco de tempo e vontade para entender seu funcionamento, mas em si, não vale a pena. Compensa muito mais estudar novos algoritmos que estão "seguros" hoje.

Mas se quiser se aventurar, [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) está a melhor explicação encontrada.

Em suma, não é nada recomendável usar esse algoritmo em nenhuma das situações este algoritmo. Existem melhores, mais rápidos e principalmente, mais seguros que o mesmo.